# Flutter: Pre-load data into Firestore local cache on the first load

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, preload, offline-caching

I've implemented Cloud Firestore into my Flutter app and encountered this problem: if there's no network connection on the very first load of the app (after installation), no data is shown. 
**My question is: How to make so that the data from Firestore is shown on the first load (after installation) even without internet connection?** My code for fetching data is this:

```
class QuestionsListState extends State<QuestionsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _questionsCollectionReference
          .where("category", isEqualTo: _chosenCategory).orderBy("order").snapshots,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('');
        final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: messageCount,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return new ListTile(
              title: new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => new AddAnswerDialog(),
                      fullscreenDialog: true,
                    ));
                  },
                  child: new Text(
                    document['text'],
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.blue),
                  )),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation. The solution for me was to load that data from disk, by using a `FutureBuilder` instead of `const Text('')`

In other words, your structure would be:

- StreamBuilder

  - when `hasData` is false

    - FutureBuilder

      - when `hasData` is false

        - show a `CircularProgress`
      - when `hasData` is true

        - show disk data
  - when `hasData` is true

    - show online data

For a first-time user, this will show a `CircularProgress`, followed by data from disk, followed by online data. If the online data does not load (no network), the user keeps seeing the disk data.

Answer (score 0):

Could just check whether any data is already cached before adding again.

Have also found this flutter info YouTube video by Tensor Programming useful [Making Use of Utility Plugins for Dart's Flutter Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLKtx2HzqXc) especially the connectivity status part.

Answer (score -3):

Would this do it? Haven't tried yet but looking at doing similar for an offline initially National Park app next month.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('<collection>').document().setData(
        {
          '<field>': '<data>',
        },
      );
```

uses cloud firestore plugin > https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: Yes it does, but I need to do it only once - on the very first load after installation. So I'll think about placing the code in the right place or trying to put cache along with app files in apk. Thanks!

Comment: I really dont see what it has to do with the question